# In Oracle, how do I get a page of distinct values from sorted results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns in a one-to-many relationship.  I want to sort on the "many" and return the first occurrence of the "one".  I need to page through the data so, for example, I need to be able to get the 3rd group of 10 unique "one" values.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.fkid = table1.id
ORDER BY name, id;
```

There can be multiple rows in table2 for each row in table1.

The results of my query look like this:

```
  id   |  name
----------------
   2   | apple
  23   | banana
  77   | cranberry
  23   | dark chocolate
   8   | egg
   2   | yak
  19   | zebra
```

I need to page through the result set with each page containing n **unique** ids. For example, if start=1 and n=4 I want to get back

```
 2
23
77
 8
```

in the order they were sorted on (i.e., name), where id is returned in the position of its first occurrence.  Likewise if start=3 and n=4 and order = desc I want

```
 8
23
77
 2
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, ROWNUM rnum FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (
      SELECT id, name
      FROM table1
      INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.fkid = table1.id
      ORDER BY name, id)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 4)
  WHERE rnum >=1)
```

which gave me the ids in numerical order, instead of being ordered as the names would be.

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, ROWNUM rnum FROM (
    SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT id, name
      FROM table1
      INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.fkid = table1.id
      ORDER BY name, id)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 4)
  WHERE rnum >=1)
```

but that gave me duplicate values.

How can I page through the results of this data?  I just need the ids, nothing from the "many" table.

**update**

I suppose I'm getting closer with changing my inner query to

```
SELECT id, name, rank() over (order by name, id)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.fkid = table1.id
```

...but I'm still getting duplicate ids.

Comment: If you need to paginate results your application's search functionality is probably broken.  Read this recent blog by Jeff Atwood (late of this parish): http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/the-end-of-pagination.html

Comment: Thanks for the link; it was an interesting read.  However, I am not displaying search results.  A finite amount of data is displayed and the amount depends on the user's role.  It is sometimes more than should go on a single page (or be held in a JavaScript component), though it is my plan to move to continuous scrolling when I get time to rework the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to debug it a little, but but it will be something like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT id, name, row_number() over (partition by id order by name) rn
      FROM table1
      INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.fkid = table1.id
      )
   ) WHERE rn=1 ORDER BY name, id
  ) WHERE rownum>=1 and rownum<=4;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and it's fast too. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit convoluted (and I would tend to suspect that it could be simplified) but it should work.  You'd can put whatever start and end position you want in the `WHERE` clause-- I'm showing here with start=2 and n=4 are pulled from a separate table but you could simplify things by using a couple of parameters instead.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 2 id, 'apple' name from dual union all
  3    select 23, 'banana' from dual union all
  4    select 77, 'cranberry' from dual union all
  5    select 23, 'dark chocolate' from dual union all
  6    select 8, 'egg' from dual union all
  7    select 2, 'yak' from dual union all
  8    select 19, 'zebra' from dual
  9  ),
 10  x as (
 11    select 2 start_pos, 4 n from dual
 12  )
 13  select *
 14    from (
 15      select distinct
 16             id,
 17             dense_rank() over (order by min_id_rnk) outer_rnk
 18        from (
 19          select id,
 20                 min(rnk) over (partition by id) min_id_rnk
 21            from (
 22              select id,
 23                     name,
 24                     rank() over (order by name) rnk
 25                from t
 26             )
 27        )
 28    )
 29   where outer_rnk between (select start_pos from x) and (select start_pos+n-1 from x)
 30*  order by outer_rnk
SQL> /

        ID  OUTER_RNK
---------- ----------
        23          2
        77          3
         8          4
        19          5
```